# How to fix and keep the table in the page?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
%\footnotesize
%\tabcolsep
%\arraycolsep
%\node (table) [inner sep=0pt]{
%\footnotesize
\caption{Potential of nanotechnology applications in petroleum industry}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.7\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}}  
%\textbf{\hline Objective & Area}\\
\hline \bfseries Objective & \bfseries Area \\ 
\hline  Improved success ratio of exploration by improving data gathering, recognizing shallow hazards and avoiding dry holes.& Exploration \\ 
\hline Improved performance and reliability in drilling, tubular goods and rotating parts by improving the strength and endurance of the material pH (4-5\% in dispersion) & Drilling \\ 
\hline  Production assurance in diagnostics, monitoring surveillance and management strategies&Production  \\ 
\hline  Corrosion management for surface and subsurface & Production \\ 
\hline  Corrosion management for surface and subsurface & Facilities \\ 
\hline  Refining and petrochemical technologies& Downstream  \\ 
\hline Enhanced oil and gas recovery through reservoir property modification, gas and water injection modification. & Reservoir \\ 
\hline
\label{potofnan}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I have issues to contain that table in the A4 page. Someone can fix it  for me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020?s=1|0.0000#39020) might answer your question. Please do post full examples, not fragments of code

Comment: What exactly are the issues? Which font size and font do you use? How are the page margins set? The body of the `tabular` environment would appear to contain only two columns, yet the header sets up five columns -- are the last three needed?

Answer (score 1):

The setup of your `tabular` environment is a bit confusing: The header defines the format for five columns, yet the body of the environment uses only two columns.

I suggest you switch from `tabular` to `tabularx`, let the table take up the full width of the text block, and omit all vertical rules and most of the horizontal rules. And, by replacing `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` with `\setlength\extrarowheight{1ex}`, the table will end up occupying much less of the page, giving you a better chance of getting the table to fit on the intended page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, % for tabularx environment
            ragged2e, % for \RaggedRight macro
            booktabs, % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule macros
            caption}  % for better spacing below caption
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\extrarowheight{1ex} % extra vertical whitespace between rows
\caption{Potential of nanotechnology applications in petroleum industry} 
\label{potofnan}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} Y l @{} }  
\toprule
Objective & Area \\ 
\midrule
Improved success ratio of exploration by improving data gathering, 
    recognizing shallow hazards and avoiding dry holes & Exploration \\ 
Improved performance and reliability in drilling, tubular goods and 
    rotating parts by improving the strength and endurance of the material 
    pH (4--5\% in dispersion) & Drilling \\ 
Production assurance in diagnostics, monitoring surveillance and management 
    strategies & Production  \\   
Corrosion management for surface and subsurface & Production \\   
Corrosion management for surface and subsurface & Facilities \\   
Refining and petrochemical technologies & Downstream  \\ 
Enhanced oil and gas recovery through reservoir property modification, gas 
    and water injection modification & Reservoir \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```